# PostgreSQL: Create an index for fields within a composite type?

Tags: postgresql, types, indexing

Is it possible to have an index on a certain field of a composite type? Assume, for instance, I create a type

```
CREATE TYPE complex AS (
    r       double precision,
    i       double precision
);
```

and would like to have an (especially Hash/GIST/GIN) index over `r` and one over `i`, would that be possible?

Similarly, is it possible to have an index over the first, the second, the third,... element of an array field?

Assume I use `complex[]`, would it be possible to have an index over all `complex[0]`, over all `complex[1]`, etc.

Comment: Advanced index usage, might be a candidate for migration to [dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, absolutely possible. Use an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html). The tricky part is the [syntax for composite types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-ACCESSING).

B-tree index on an element of a complex type:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (tbl_id serial, co complex);

CREATE INDEX tbl_co_r_idx ON tbl (((co).r)); -- note the parentheses!
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3a25fb78914019c92eee9e7d136f176b)* - with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ce2dc/2)</sub>

Same thing works for a pre-determined element of an array (not for the whole array!), even for an array of composite type:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl2 (tbl2_id serial, co complex[]);

CREATE INDEX tbl2_co1_idx ON tbl2 ((co[1])); -- note the parentheses!
```

Note that the expression-index can only be used for queries if the expression is matched more or less literally.

But that doesn't make sense with a **GIN** index like you mention. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-intro.html):

> GIN stands for Generalized Inverted Index. GIN is designed for
> handling cases where the items to be indexed are composite values, and
> the queries to be handled by the index need to search for element
> values that appear within the composite items.

A GIN index would make sense on an array of complex type *as a whole*, to let you search for an element within. But you need an implementation for your particular type. Here is a [list of examples in standard Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-examples.html) (in addition to basic support for all one-dimensional arrays).

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed and good answer! Thanks also for the hint regarding _GIN_, you are completely right there!

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter your second situation/example is very close to what I need too. Though I need to be able to query rows which have elements in co which match some predicate -> though not necessarily on the whole, but say just the r field.

Is there some way to "unnest" the array into a single GIN index, or alternatively somehow a btree index on all internal co.r fields, not just one array entry's r field. So basically ANY on a composite/complex type with the ((co).r) like index.

Comment: @Climax: Please ask your question as *question*. You can always link to this one for context, and drop a comment here to link back.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've created the question in the dba stack https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/307484/69985